# Getting "error MSB3030: Could not copy the file" when no Copy is provided in project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

After migrating project from Visual Studio 2015 to Visual Studio 2015 I started to get the following error:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4358,5): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "C:\p4client\ProAudio\dev_main_2018\ProAudio\XPlatform\AudioGrid\sdk\Project\Win\ag_sgring.pb.cc ag_sgring_pb2.py" because it was not found.

However, in no place in project copy step was not specified.
How can I find out what is asking this copy step and disable it?
Was there any change between VS 2015 and VS 20017 in copy tasks?

Comment: That looks like two files, one with a .cc extension and another with .py.  So sure, that isn't going to work.  If you have no idea where this came from then turn the build verbosity to eleven.  Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run.